# Change DIV border color with form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, input

I am using a DIV "find_frame" to wrap an input field.

I need to change the DIV "find_frame border color if the validation stops the submit.

How do I do this?

```
<form>
    <div class="find_frame">
        <input type="text" id="find" name="find" placeholder="Enter Number">
    </div>
    <input id="findbutton" type="button" value="FIND ME">
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try a pattern like this:

```
var $ff = $('.find_frame');
var $input = $('#find');
var $button = $('#findbutton');

function PUTVALIDATIONHERE(value) {
    return false;
}

$button.click(function() {
    var value = $input.val();
    if (!PUTVALIDATIONHERE(value)) {
        $ff.css("borderColor", "red");

        // or use a css class
        $ff.addClass('validationError');
    }
});
```

If the validation you need is to check whether the input is a number or not, replace the PUTVALIDATIONHERE function with this:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Adding a class is almost always better than using .css() but I won't downvote just for that. The idea is correct

Comment: @mhodges good point. I added an example of adding the css class

Comment: @Erik put the code I have above within `script` tags. Make sure you implement the `PUTVALIDATIONHERE` function (I left that has a placeholder)

Comment: Thank you, I need to learn more about validation.  Not sure what to put in the PUTVALDATION.  I thank you anyway

Comment: @Erik, I updated my answer with a function that validates whether the input is numeric

Comment: Thank you for the help follow through.  appreciate it.